# How to enable submit button after failed validations controller- Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, validation, form-submit

My data is validated in controller when the form is submitted. After adapting the fields causing the failed validations, submitting is no longer possible (submit button is enabled).
In my network monitor I got the code 302 (failed redirect, I can't get out of it)
The data can be submitted only when the page is reloaded but then all the data is lost and the user has to fill in the form all over again.
How can I resubmit the data after failed validations?

In the ProjectController.php you will find the validation of the fields. I guess after the validation fails I am out the form. And I need to get into the form again to be able to submit.
Thanks for the help.

#### ProjectController.php

```
  public function store(Request $request, Project $project)
    {
        // Validate fields
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name'                  => 'required|min:3',
            'mail'                  => 'required|email', 
            'intern_extern'         => 'required',
            'institute'             => 'min:2',
            'project'               => 'required|min:3',

        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/projects/create')
                ->back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }

        $project = new project();
        $project->name = request('name');
        $project->mail = request('mail');
        $project->intern_extern = request('intern_extern');
        $project->institute = request('institute');
        $project->project_name = request('project');
        $project->status = project::STATUS_NEW;

        $project->save();

        return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'New project is create');
    }
```

#### create.blade.php

```
<form action="/projects" method="POST" id="create_project" >
@csrf
@include('error')


<!-- Create a New project -->
<div class="card">
    <h1 class="card-header text-center">Create New project</h1>

    <!-- Start contact info -->
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">Contact info</h3>
        <div class="card-text"> 

            <!-- Start row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="p-1">
                            <label class="p-2" for="name">Name*</label>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-4"> 
                    <div class="d-flex">                       
                        <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                            <input type="text" 
                                    class="form-control input-text"
                                    placeholder="name"
                                    name="name"
                                    value="{{old('name')}}"
                                    required
                            >
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="p-1">
                            <label class="p-2" for="mail">Email*</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4"> 
                    <div class="d-flex">   
                        <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                            <input type="email" 
                                    class="form-control input-text"
                                    placeholder="Email" 
                                    name="mail"
                                    value="{{old('mail')}}"
                                    required
                            >
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>     
            </div> <!-- End row -->

            <!-- Start row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="p-1">
                            <label class="p-2" for="intern_extern">Intern*</label>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4"> 
                    <div class="d-flex">                    
                        <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                            <select name="intern_extern" class="form-control" id="YesNo" onchange="displayInstitute()" required>
                                <option>{{old('intern_extern')}}</option>
                                <option id="isYes">Yes</option>
                                <option id="isNo">No</option>
                            </select>
                            <p><font id="result" color="dodgerBlue"></font></p>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="p-1" >
                            <label id="institute_label" class="p-2" for="institute" style="display: none;">Institute*</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-4"> 
                    <div class="d-flex">   
                        <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                            <select name="institute" class="form-control" id="ifyes" style="display: none;">
                                <option>{{old('institute')}}</option>
                                <option>QZA</option>
                                <option>PB</option>
                                <option>LET</option>

                            </select>
                            <input type="text" id="ifno" style="display: none;"
                                    class="form-control input-text" 
                                    name="institute"                                    
                            >
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>     
            </div> <!-- End row -->                   
        </div> <!-- End text -->
    </div>  <!-- End body -->
</div> <!-- End card -->

<!-- project -->
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-body">
        <h3 class="card-title">project</h3>
        <div class="card-text"> 

            <!-- start row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <div class="p-1">
                            <label class="p-2" for="project">Name*</label>
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                </div> 
                <div class="col-4"> 
                    <div class="d-flex">                       
                        <div class="flex-fill p-2">
                            <input type="text" 
                                    class="form-control input-text" 
                                    placeholder="Project Name"
                                    name="project" 
                                    value="{{old('project')}}"
                                    required
                            >
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            </div> <!-- End row -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4 offset-4">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" style="margin: 10px;">New project</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  <!-- End body -->
</div> <!-- End card -->
    <!-- Submit field -->

</form>
```

Comment: Maybe ```redirect('/projects/create')``` is an issue. See if it works by just having ```redirect()```

Comment: @DinoNumić. I just used redirect(). It doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If any of the validation failed in main validator , it will redirect you back to the previous page. 
If you have any validation inside the function , You might need to use the

```
return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
```

Or simply use

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```

To get all the entered values back .
Try this and let me know if any error you got .

**EDIT**
You don't have to use the

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('/projects/create')
                ->back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }
```

Just leave the comment those lines and try  .
For example, in my function I just added this and I didn't used any if condition for validation . 
Remove the variable $validator .

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name'                  => 'required|min:3',
            'mail'                  => 'required|email', 
            'intern_extern'         => 'required',
            'institute'             => 'min:2',
            'project'               => 'required|min:3',

        ]);
```

Instead of that use the following method .

```
$this->validate($request, [
'registration' => 'required|string|max:30',
'documentType' => 'required'
]);
```

Comment: I filled in for name only t => then I got the following error "The name must be at least 3 characters". If I know try to submit the form. The submit button isn't working.

Comment: @Nemo I have edited my question . take a look at it

Comment: I tried this before. But it wasn't working. I tried again now, sadly it doesn't work. For some reason after I press the submit button. I can't go back to the form in order to submit when validation failed the first time or I have to reload the page.

Comment: I don't get an error. I redirect to the create.blade.php page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198935/discussion-between-farooq-and-nemo).

Answer (score 1):

you are giving the redirect function an argument while you are using `->back()`. the correct way would be the following. Also take a look at the [document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#validation-quickstart). You don't need to do this manually.

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
                ->withInput();
        }
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. I can't enter my form again, so I can't submit.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this in the controller

```
      $request->validate([
        'name'                  => 'required|min:3',
        'mail'                  => 'required|email', 
        'intern_extern'         => 'required',
        'institute'             => 'min:2',
        'project'               => 'required|min:3',

    ]);
```

It will automatically redirect you to the previous page if the validation gets failed .

Comment: I tried it. But still after adapting the fields who failed the validations. The submit button isn't working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the input of @Hadi and @farooq, I finally got it working. I can resubmit a form after validation in the controller fails and adapting the fields causing the failed validations. I don't quite understand why this helps but it works. This [link](https://www.sitepoint.com/data-validation-laravel-right-way/) helped me (Data Validation in Laravel: The Right Way).

#### create.blade.php (place this just above my form)

```
@if ( ! $errors->isEmpty() )
    <div class="row">
        @foreach ( $errors->all() as $error )
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 alert alert-danger">{{ $error }}</div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
@elseif ( Session::has( 'message' ) )
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-2 alert alert-success">{{ Session::get( 'message' ) }}</div>
    </div>
@else
        <p>&nbsp;</p>
@endif
```

#### ProjectController.php (used this in my controller)

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```